# SlickGrid: 2 questions: 1) change the orientation of column labels and 2) display d3.js elements inside cells

Tags: d3.js, slickgrid, dashboard

New to SlickGrid here, and have a couple questions:

1) Is it possible to change the orientation of the column labels? I would like to display a grid without horizontal scrolling, and the data can easily fit if I limit the width of each column. However is I do that, I dont have enough space for my column labels. So I am wondering if - like in excel - I could change the orientation of the column labels (to say 45 degreees vs. horizontal)? If not, any other suggestion?

2) Is it possible to display D3.js type elements (shapes etc) inside cells? If not, are there options to display things such as color coded stop-lights type things?

As you might have guessed, I am building a dashboard that pulls data from a summary table in a DB, and need visual eye candy. It's probably all doable in D3.js, but I'm looking for a faster way to implement, and a data grid appears appropriate.